# Collect function power apps

Tags: powerapps, power-platform

I can't collect Thisitem into my collection called `colMaterialesSeleccionados`:

[image]

I tried the syntax:

```
  Collect(colMaterialesSeleccionados,{
  InvtID: Thisitem.InvtID;
  Descr: Thisitem.Descr
  })
```

[image]

But this doesnt work and marks error. Alternatively, I tried this to see if something happend:

```
  Collect(colMaterialesSeleccionados,{
  Thisitem.InvtID
  })
```

And a new column is added with the name Value: [image]

Comment: What is the error that you get with the first expression?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong syntax.  The second line should end with a comma, according to the [Microsoft Learn Page for Collect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-clear-collect-clearcollect).
So it should be:

```
  Collect(colMaterialesSeleccionados,{
  InvtID: Thisitem.InvtID,
  Descr: Thisitem.Descr
  })
```

Comment: I solved it. The syntax is ok. The problem was that I was declaring previously an empty collection called colMaterialesSeleccionados with Black() fields. So when I tried to populate those fields the field type didn't match